# how to use table without join in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

i have multiple tables related with each other but i have one table not related to anyone of this tables and want to use this table within (where clause). So how do I do this?

```
 /*  this is the table i want to use without join (d_checkupnext_alert.chx_days)
  *  notice : chx_days return on value with one row only
  */

SELECT 
  d_checkupinfo.*,
  d_branch.*,
  d_checkup.*,
  d_patient.*,
  d_checkupnext_alert.chx_days
FROM d_checkupinfo
  LEFT JOIN d_patient ON d_checkupinfo.chi_pi_num = d_patient.pi_id
  LEFT JOIN d_branch ON d_checkupinfo.chi_branch_id = d_branch.branch_id
  LEFT JOIN d_checkup ON d_checkupinfo.chi_type_id = d_checkup.checkup_id
   WHERE CURDATE() BETWEEN DATE_SUB(FROM_UNIXTIME(chi_nextdate), INTERVAL chx_days day) AND FROM_UNIXTIME(chi_nextdate)
```

/* update */
i use this code and it works but give me errors

```
 SET @days = (select chx_days from d_checkupnext_alert LIMIT 1);
 SELECT d_checkupinfo.*, d_branch.*, d_checkup.*,
d_patient.* 
FROM d_checkupinfo
  LEFT JOIN d_patient ON d_checkupinfo.chi_pi_num = d_patient.pi_id
  LEFT JOIN d_branch ON d_checkupinfo.chi_branch_id = d_branch.branch_id
  LEFT JOIN d_checkup ON d_checkupinfo.chi_type_id = d_checkup.checkup_id 
WHERE CURDATE() BETWEEN DATE_SUB(FROM_UNIXTIME(chi_nextdate), INTERVAL @days day) AND FROM_UNIXTIME(chi_nextdate)
```

Comment: It doesn't make sense to `SELECT` something with a `WHERE` clause concerning an independent table. What do you want exactly ? Does `d_checkupnext_alert` have multiple rows ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best way is to use a simple `JOIN` or a '`,`' like this :

```
SELECT 
  d_checkupinfo.*,
  d_branch.*,
  d_checkup.*,
  d_patient.*,
  d_checkupnext_alert.chx_days
FROM d_checkupinfo
  LEFT JOIN d_patient ON d_checkupinfo.chi_pi_num = d_patient.pi_id
  LEFT JOIN d_branch ON d_checkupinfo.chi_branch_id = d_branch.branch_id
  LEFT JOIN d_checkup ON d_checkupinfo.chi_type_id = d_checkup.checkup_id
  , d_checkupnext_alert
   WHERE CURDATE() BETWEEN DATE_SUB(FROM_UNIXTIME(chi_nextdate), INTERVAL chx_days day) AND FROM_UNIXTIME(chi_nextdate)
```

But if you don't want, you could use System Variables : see ["MySQL System Variables"](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/using-system-variables.html)

Comment: And why don't you want to use a JOIN ?